# Is functional programming affordable in scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

1. Is functional programming affordable in scala?  What I mean by affordability is copying the immutable data structure like a list when passed by value to a pure function without worrying about memory.  Is this not inefficient without a clojure like persistent data structure implementation in place?
2. If pure functional programming is affordable in scala, then  are there any high performance open source projects that used pure scala functional programming?

Comment: Scala lists are persistent.

Comment: You should never stop worrying about memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Scala provides persistent data structures which make use of
   structural sharing, so yes, it is "affordable".
2. Take a look at [akka](http://akka.io/) and [Play](http://www.playframework.com/). Apart from that, large parts of Twitter are based on Scala, you can read about it [here](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/twitter_on_scala.html).

> What I mean by affordability is copying the immutable data structure
>   like a list when passed by value to a pure function without worrying
>   about memory

Not sure if I get what you want to say but passing objects to functions does not copy anything but the reference to the object. It is still the same object you are working on inside of the function.